# Do 404 errors impact performance?

Tags: javascript, nginx

I have a few scripts included in some web pages that no longer exist.  People get tons of 404s because the pages are high traffic.  I just removed them, but, does it impact performance if I were to leave these in?

Comment: If the browser cannot obtain a resource, it shouldn't be asking in the first place.

Comment: Every 404 is still an http request/response transaction. Of course "tons" of these would impact performance, whether you're talking about server time, browser performance, or bloated log files.

Answer (score 1):

They certainly do, as they are unnecessary request/response interactions that can add to page load time.

Yahoo explains it very well in their "[Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#no404)".

In your particular case, my suggestion is use a tool such as [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) or [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) to determine how big is the impact of the 404 responses.

Answer (score 0):

You still have the request/response communication between client and server, even if a 404 is sent back. However, no processing is needed (such as PHP or other server-side languages) so you will recover some of the load but it's still best not to leave the 404 references in there.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you're asking about broken links vs valid links, or if you're asking about broken links vs no links at all.

So I did some testing for all three scenarios.  In my test I used links to images, so links to documents might give you different results.  I created a test page that loads 100 unique images.  I loaded it five times with images and five times with broken image links (creating 404 errors), and five times without any image tags at all.  Each time before loading the page I cleared my cache to make sure it was a fair fight.

With 100 images these were my results:

```
3138 milliseconds
3102 milliseconds
2721 milliseconds
4105 milliseconds
3365 milliseconds
```

With 100 broken image links:

```
1700 milliseconds
1706 milliseconds
1734 milliseconds
1661 milliseconds
1678 milliseconds
```

With image tags removed entirely:

```
10 milliseconds
13 milliseconds
21 milliseconds
12 milliseconds
12 milliseconds
```

So a broken link is faster than a valid link, but it's still slower than no link at all.  If you don't need them, it might be worth getting rid of them.